# What is the right way to calculate gas price and limit for contract deployment?

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, metamask, out-of-gas

I have tried several times and reached up to a `gasPrice` of 65 Gwei and a `gasLimit` of `500,000` which is $7.6 and still the deployment fails with error "Out of gas".

After spending tens of USD without getting the fees back - how can I calculate how much gas will be enough for deploying my contract?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Remix and MetaMask (ass your tags imply), then it should be calculated for you automatically (they use the `eth_estimateGas` RPC call under the hood). If that is the case, you should not manually enter a `gasLimit` of `500,000` and instead use their estimated gas.

As a note, any gas that is unused in the transaction is returned to you. For example, if your contract costs `1,000,000` gas to deploy and you use `gasLimit = 5,000,000`, then your contract will be deployed and you will only have spent `1,000,000` gas.